# Type name not allowed (Convert)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have two textBox, a button and a textBox where the result will be

```
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double z = 0;
        x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1->Text);   
        y = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
        z = x + y;
        textBox3->Text = Convert.ToString(z);
    }
```

"Convert" write error number E0254

Comment: Translate the question title in English

Comment: If ToDouble is a static member function then you need to write  x = Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `ToDouble` and `ToString` are static member functions then instead of

```
x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1->Text);   
y = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
textBox3->Text = Convert.ToString(z);
```

you need to write

```
x = Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);   
y = Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
textBox3->Text = Convert::ToString(z);
```